# How best to store pre-existing data in iphone app?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

I want to make an iphone app that uses some preexisting data. For example I want to have 20 questions with their relative answer stored somewhere, so that I can use them in the app.

I thought about adding an existing sqlite3 database, but I was wondering how could I then map it with core data? Can I just import the db and set it somewhere? Or is an xml better suited for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a large dataset, then using sqlite and its associated API is a good way to do it. It will take care of indexing, memory management, etc.

But if the dataset is small enough that you can just suck it all into memory from a file, then just do that; there is no reason to complicate things with Core Data.

Comment: It's going to be 200-500 records (string < 150 characters), each of those with 4 answers. I think I'm going to try with a file for now.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just 20 items, and all of them are basic types like strings, you can create a XML based plist. You can create/edit them in XCode, or any editor really.

Then at run time you can read that in with something like:

```
[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: somePath];
```

Check the property list programming guide for the ifs, ands, and buts. But an array of questions and answers would be just fine.